# When is onAttach called during the Fragment LifeCycle?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Exactly when is `onAttach` called during the Fragment-Activity lifecycles?

I am aware of the Fragment Life-Cycle but exactly when?

Is it when the fragment object is initiated or when fragment manager is called?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In activity the first method is onCreate.
onCreate of activity add the fragment and in this moment onAttach is called. like in the picture

[image]

Ref: https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle

Comment: It would be nice to add onSaveInstaceState to the scheme

Comment: Where would onViewCreated from fragment be in this scheme ?

Comment: This is a very old diagram. onFreeze() has been renamed to onSaveInstanceState() in Android 0.9 SDK Beta. See https://developer.android.com/sdk/OLD_RELEASENOTES.html

Comment: This flow is incomplete. Some events can halt the activity execution. For example, activity `onDestroy` will not be called if the system is running out of memory and kills the process. Activity `onStart` will not be called if you call finish from Activity onCreate. The edge cases in Fragments are even scarier, so I am not even diving into those...

Answer (score 1):

onAttach is called after Fragment is associated with its Activity.

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context)