# Fragment.isVisible() returns false even when Fragment added and visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am perplexed by how Fragment.isVisible() is supposed to work. Even though I have a fragment added in `Activity.create()`, `Fragment.isVisible()` returns false even when `FragmentManager.commitNow()` is used.

`Fragment.isVisible()` returns false even in `onResume()`. However, when a UI button gets clicked the returned value is correct.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public final static String TAG = "HideFragmentOnChange";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button)).setOnClickListener(this);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Before FragmentTransaction FragA: " + (fragmentA.isVisible() ? "visible" : "not visible"));

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentA, "fragA")
                .commitNow();

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: After FragmentTransaction FragA: " + (fragmentA.isVisible() ? "visible" : "not visible"));

    }

    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Fragment fragA = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragA");
            Log.d(TAG, "runOnUiThread after onCreate(): FragA: " + (fragA.isVisible() ? "visible" : "not visible"));
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Fragment fragA = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragA");
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume: FragA: " + (fragA.isVisible() ? "visible" : "not visible"));

    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Fragment fragA = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragA");
            Log.d(TAG, "runOnUiThread after onResume(): FragA: " + (fragA.isVisible() ? "visible" : "not visible"));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment fragmentA = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragA");
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick(): FragA: " + (fragmentA.isVisible() ? "visible" : "not visible"));
}
```

}

I initially thought that perhaps it is because the main thread has not had the chance to run yet and the `FragmentTransaction` does not fully and properly commit until a later point. However, calling `runOnUiThread` does not change the return value of `isVisible()`.

I am attaching the log for reference.

```
03-15 17:22:34.978 14094-14094/ D/HideFragmentOnChange: onCreate: Before FragmentTransaction FragA: not visible
03-15 17:22:34.990 14094-14094/ D/HideFragmentOnChange: onCreate: After FragmentTransaction FragA: not visible
03-15 17:22:34.991 14094-14094/ D/HideFragmentOnChange: runOnUiThread after onCreate(): FragA: not visible
03-15 17:22:34.996 14094-14094/ D/HideFragmentOnChange: onResume: FragA: not visible
03-15 17:22:34.996 14094-14094/ D/HideFragmentOnChange: runOnUiThread after onResume(): FragA: not visible
03-15 17:22:56.683 14094-14094/ D/HideFragmentOnChange: onClick(): FragA: visible
```

Why does `Fragment.isVisible()` seem to return the correct value with such a big delay?

I am using support library 25.2 and support library Fragments although native fragments produced the same behavior.

Answer (score 5):

There is a method for Fragments :

```
     getUserVisibleHint();
```

You can find more information in [official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getUserVisibleHint()).

It gives "true" when fragment is visible to user and "false" when it is invisible.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setUserVisibleHint`

Form the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean))

> Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently
>   visible to the user. This hint defaults to true and is persistent
>   across fragment instance state save and restore.

To use it:

```
    private static boolean isVisible;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) { 
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    isVisible = isVisibleToUser;

    if (isVisible) { 
        Log.d("TAG", "this fragment is visible");
    } else {  
        Log.d("TAG", "this fragment is invisible");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that the Fragment also has his own lifecycle. You are basically calling it way too early. A Fragment is deemed visible if

[Fragment#isVisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isVisible())

> Return true if the fragment is currently visible to the user. This means it: (1) has been added, (2) **has its view attached to the window**, and (3) is not hidden.

See this SO post about the lifecycle of the Activity/Fragment
[When is onAttach called during the Fragment LifeCycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339811/when-is-onattach-called-during-the-fragment-lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that on opening a fragment and going through all the lifecycle 
(onAttach, onCreate, onStart etc..), calling isVisible() from onResume() will return **false**. However, if you only stop the fragment (i.e pressing the home button), isVisible() will return **true**.
Conclusion: Keep a class boolean flag:

```
   private mFirstTimeVisible = true;
```

and use it in the following onResume check:

```
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       if (mFistTimeVisible || isVisible()) { 
          //your code...
       }
       mFistTimeVisible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, just call isVisible by some delay

```
 @Override
       public void onResume() {
           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("ONRESUME", isVisible() );
            }
        }, 100);
           
 }
```